# Move Files on Mass By Name to New Directory

Tags: windows-10

I have a folder containing nearly 100 sub folders, each of those having their own subdirectories containing models, effects etc. I need to move roughly half of them to a different folder. All the files and folders follow the same naming scheme, for example `m8a_rev1` `m8a_rev2` `m8a_rev3`

I have a list of each item that needs to be moved so I'm looking for a way that I can move these folders and files by name as opposed to having to do it manually due to time constraints. The best I could find so far is [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) but I'm unsure how I could use an entire list with them

Thanks for any support

Comment: Need more info on your "list". Is it a text file with one file per line and each an absolute path to the file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to move every file to the same directory, use `xcopy <source> <destination> -q -e -t`. This moves all of the files within the directory, as well as every subdirectory and file within each subdirectory.

`-q` suppresses the info in the `xcopy` window, which you can omit if you want to see file progress.

`-e` copies all subdirectories.

`-t` copies the subdirectory tree, allowing the files to be moved to their correct subdirectory.